# hdfs or hadoop command to sync the files or folder between local to hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a local files which gets added daily so I want to sync these newly added files to hdfs.

I tried below command but all are complete copy, I want some command which copies only newly added files

```
$ hdfs dfs -cp /home/user/files/* /data/files/*
```

Comment: Are you able to install extra software such as Apache NiFi? If not, you need to write some code that tracks which files are added and/or missing from HDFS compared to your local dir... There is no "rsync" feature for HDFS

Comment: Did you consider HDFS Fuse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hsync. 
https://github.com/alexholmes/hsync

Its Alex's custom package and perhaps useful on a dev box but could be hard to deploy on production environment. I am looking for a similar solution but for now this seems to be closest. Other option is to write your own shell script to compare source/target file times and then overwrite newer files only.